# HTML CSS Website not moving navigation bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

My CSS style sheet doesn't seem to be working?

Anyone know why?

Code:

```css
/* my css style sheet named "style" */


/* CSS Selector applicable to all elements which in this case are my html margin padding and box size */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20%;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: right;
}

nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Drake</title>
  <!-- Name of my website -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" href="style.css">
  <!-- Link to my css style sheet -->

</head>

<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <!-- Navigation bar class created -->
    <!-- May have to potentially change variable name-->
    <div class="logo">
      <!-- Logo class with navigation created -->
      <img src="https://logo.clearbit.com/spotify.com" width="125px " alt="owl logo">
      <!-- owl logo inserted and resized -->
    </div>
    <nav>
      <!-- Naviagation element created ....  -->
      <ul>
        <!-- Along with an ordered list of different pages subject to change  -->
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Account</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What part of this is not working? What is the desired result?

Comment: my navigation bar is meant to show up on the left and to be horizontal

Comment: The list ive made is under the logo anythime i run it on google chrome but when i go on
https://html-css-js.com/
it seems ot work fine

Answer (score 0):

If possible, could you please specify what result is expected or what are trying to achieve?
If you would like to make navigation "sticky" so it would be always visible to users even if they scroll down the page, then as an option you could try to add to your .navbar class CSS this:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: my navigation bar is meant to show up on the left and to be horizontal

Comment: The list ive made is under the logo anythime i run it on google chrome but when i go on
https://html-css-js.com/
it seems ot work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to put the nabber in the top left corner of the screen, you can remove the `padding: 20%` from your "navbar" class (.navbar).

Comment: my navigation bar is meant to show up on the left and to be horizontal

Comment: The list ive made is under the logo anytime i run it on google chrome but when i go on
https://html-css-js.com/
it seems ot work fine

Comment: It still doesn't work. I'm using visual studio code if that helps

Comment: If you use Chrome dev tools (Right click on your nav bar and choose 'Inspect Element'), Under 'Elements' make sure you click/highlight <div class="nabber">.

Comment: In the 'Styles' section you should see your styles from your style.css:9 (line 9 in your style.css file) for .navbar {display: flex; align-items: center; padding: 20%;
Try unchecking the box next to padding: 20% and let me know if the navbar moves to where you want it. You can play with it by changing the value and when correct, change your css file to match. It looks ok to me after removing the padding but I am not sure exactly what you want.

Comment: should be <div class="navbar"> the auto correct keeps changing it to nabber.